# Can you only get the silver sword from the store?

Tags: the-witcher-monster-slayer

The game The Witcher - Monster Slayer has just released, and I find myself wanting to get into it as fast as possible.

Several of the enemys are weak to silver, which makes sense according to the lore. There are some bombs that inflict silver-damage, and there is also the option of equipping the silver sword; you just need to get it first.

In addition to buying it for 1800 coins in the store, is there any other, perhaps story related, way to aquire the silver sword?